# @AttributeOverride not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the code

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class AbstractModel implements Serializable, Comparable<AbstractModel> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4479726024447228668L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idgen")
    private Long              id;
    ...


@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class AbstractHistoricModel extends AbstractModel {

    private static final long     serialVersionUID = -3596885940998632065L;

    @Column(name = "pblc_id")
    ...


@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(initialValue = 0, name = "idgen", sequenceName = "abstract_claim_type_seq")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AbstractClaimType extends AbstractHistoricModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3840541568639732203L;

    @Column(name = "nam")
    private String            name;

    public AbstractClaimType() { super(); }

    @Field
    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }
    ...


@Entity
@Table("retr_clm_mthd")
@SequenceGenerator….
@FieldModel
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@AttributeOverride(name="nam", column=@Column(name="retr_clm_mthd_nam", length=255))  
public class Retrospective extends AbstractClaimType {
...
```

and when I create the database in memory to test

```
2013-04-11 14:15:28,445 ERROR (org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport:org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:386))  - HHH000231: Schema export unsuccessful

org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ImportScriptException: Error during statement execution (file: '/import.sql')

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column not found: RETR_CLM_MTHD_NAM in statement
```

I look the scriptdb and there is

```
CREATE MEMORY TABLE RETR_CLM_MTHD(….,NAM VARCHAR(255),….)
```

Why not `retr_clm_mthd_nam`?
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any attribute named "nam" in the superclass. You have one named "name":

```
private String name;
```

Comment: Hi,

    @Column(name = "nam")
     private String            name;
Yes I have.

    @Column is used to specify a mapped column for a persistent property or field.
Regards,

Comment: Yes. That defines the *database column name* for the attribute. The name of the attribute is `name`. **Attribute** Override is used to override the mapping of an **attribute**. It expects an **attribute** name. Not a **database column** name. Otherwise, the annotation would be **Column** Override.

Comment: Ok, but after changing my code the result is the same. @AttributeOverride(name="name"

Comment: What happens when you create this table yourself and try to load an entity from the table? Does it work? It might be a bug of the Hibernate DDL generator.

Comment: Hi, happends when I run INSERT INTO retr_clm_mthd (id, ... , retr_clm_mthd_name, ...